# Plotting vertical lines with datetime data matplotib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axvline

I would like to plot vertical lines when each new part is created on top of its features like 'Aload' or 'execution'. So I have a column called 'new_part' that indicates if a new part is created and I use it to extract the Timestamp of each new part (when new_part ==1).

```
parts_time = fn_04_num[fn_04_num['new_part'] == 1]['Timestamp']
parts_time = pd.to_datetime(parts_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The following plots with no problems

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Aload', color=color)
ax1.plot(fn_04_num['Timestamp'], fn_04_num['Aload'], color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

# instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('Status',
               color=color)

ax2.hlines(y=fn_04_num['execution'],
           xmin=fn_04_num['Timestamp'],
           xmax=fn_04_num['Timestamp2'],
           color=color)

ax2.tick_params(axis='y',
                labelcolor=color)
```

but as soon as I add this loop to get the vertical lines, I get this error

```
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
for time in parts_time:
    color = 'tab:black'
    ax3.axvline(x=time)

# Right y-label is slightly clipped
fig.tight_layout()  

plt.show()
```

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'numpy.float64'`

I verified the types of my data (Timestamp is in the same format as part_time) so I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: can't really help you without a reproducible example

Comment: You will need to use matplotlib.dates.date2num method.   Include an example and SO will show you how.